# gridview cells content right to left

Tags: android, gridview

i have grid view with numbers, but the content in the cells is ltr

[image]

however i want it to look like this, rtl

[image]

(in all cells)

Is it possible?

numbers code in xml:

```
    <!-- content-->
    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true">

        <GridView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/grid_content"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:horizontalSpacing="0dp"
            android:verticalSpacing="0dp"
            android:numColumns="6"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:background="@color/white"
            >
        </GridView>

        </ScrollView>
```

in java:

```
  GridView g3 = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.grid_content);

   String[] content = {"cont","cont" ,"cont","cont", "cont", "1"
           , "cont","cont","cont","cont","cont", "2"
           , "cont","cont","cont","cont","cont", "3"
           , "cont","cont","cont","cont","cont", "4"
           , "cont","cont","cont","cont","cont", "5"
    };

    ArrayAdapter<String> adp_content = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, content);
    g3.setAdapter(adp_content);
```

I turned the gridview clickable so you can see

[image]

what I try to achieve
[image]